# sort records on radio changes in angular

Tags: angular, sorting

I'm trying to sort the data when radio selection changes. I'm trying to call table ngOnChanges when radio value changed for storing.

[Stackblitz Repo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-99puve)

Following is my radio component which keeps track of `model.sortBy` model value.

**radio.component.html**

```
<div class="radioButtons">
    <div class="left">
        <input type="radio" value="name" ngModel="{{model.sortBy}}" (change)="changeSortBy('name')">Sort by name
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="radio" value="age" ngModel="{{model.sortBy}}" (change)="changeSortBy('age')">Sort by age
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, `changeSortBy` event triggers when radio selection changed. I want to update table records right after that, so it performs sorting based on selection.

**radio.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { TableComponent } from '../table/table.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-radio',
  providers: [RadioComponent],
  templateUrl: './radio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./radio.component.css']
})
export class RadioComponent {
  model;
  constructor() {
    this.model = {
      sortBy: "name"
    }
  }

  changeSortBy(val: string, table: TableComponent) {
    this.model = {
      sortBy: val
    }
    //table.ngOnChanges();
  }

  returnModelState() {
    //retur model.sortBy value
    return this.model.sortBy;
  }
}
```

Following is table component where data will be shown in sorted form.

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="table-div">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover full-width">
        <tr>
            <th class="course-name">Person Name</th>
            <th class="duration">Date of Birth</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let b of birthdays">
            <td  style="height:50px;" class="course-name">{{b.name}}</td>
            <td  style="height:50px;" class="duration">{{b.birth}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { RadioComponent } from '../radio/radio.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  providers: [RadioComponent],
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnChanges {
  birthdays = [
    {
      name: "User Sinha",
      birth: "12/30/2011"
    }, {
      name: "Tom Cruize",
      birth: "09/25/1992"
    }, {
      name: "Peter Jones",
      birth: "01/24/1992"
    }, {
      name: "Ammy Trigger",
      birth: "12/12/2001"
    }
  ];
  // this takes input from the radio component
  sortBy: string;
  constructor(private radio: RadioComponent) {
    this.sortBy = radio.returnModelState();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    alert("ngOnChanges: " + this.sortBy);
    this.sortItems();
  }

  sortItems() { }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out since 2 days, still can't finding out the proper solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please make a stackblitz for this? It may not be with the same components, it can contain an only a single component with your problem.

Comment: @ng-suhas Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-99puve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the stackblitz. The use of `ngOnchanges` will trigger only if there is a change in the component. So I noticed two things in stackblitz.

1. `radio` and `table` components are independent of each other.
2. `app` component is an intermediator between these two components.

So a change in radio component will not trigger the table component and so the ngOnchanges will not trigger.

So the table component should know that you have made some modifications to the radio component. Here, you can make use of `EventEmitter` and `Subject`.

1. EmitEvent from radio component to app component(event emitter)
2. Once the event is emitted, using the `Subject` send an Observable to the table component to sort it.

This is one of the right ways to do it.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-radio (event)="emitEvent($event)"></app-radio>
<app-table [sortTableSubject]="sortTableSubject.asObservable()"></app-table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  sortTableSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  emitEvent($event){
    console.log($event);
    this.sortTableSubject.next($event);
  }
}
```

**radio.component.ts**

```
changeSortBy(val: string, table: TableComponent) {
    this.model = {
      sortBy: val
    }
    this.event.emit("sortByName"); //emit what type of sorting should be done and capture that in parent component
    //table.ngOnChanges();
  }
```

**table.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sortTableSubject.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      alert("ngOnChanges: " + this.sortBy); // Capturing the event using subject
      // Do your sorting logc here
      //this.arrangeItems();
    });
  }
```

Stackblitz => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1squa2

Comment: I've tried this in my local project but `this.event.emit("sortByName");` is not triggering. What are the possible reasons? Also instead of  `ngOnInit`, we can't use `ngOnChanges` in this scenario, right?

Comment: @webdev Have you referred the stackblitz? And no, Ng OnChanges is not needed!

Comment: @webdev happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngx-order-pipe` to sort all your records.

see this examle:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-order-by

after inistall `ngx-order-pipe` use it like this: `*ngFor="let b of birthdays | orderBy: 'name'"`

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. However, I must have to follow the functions defined in table component. So, we need to sort arrays and calculate age using custom functions. Main issue is `ngOnChanges` should be called when radio value changed from radio component??

I have added stackblitz repo in my question.